# How to get all the indexes created on a label using cypher query in redisgraph

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

How to get all the indexes created on a label using cypher query in redisgraph.

I tried below command, but it returned error message.

```
CALL db.indexes();
```

ERROR:Procedure `db.indexes` is not registered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at the moment the procedure is not implemented, as such you can't query which indices already exists, but there's no harm in trying to create an already existing index. Please feel free to open an issue on our github repository asking for this capability.